# Is it possible to ride a bus as a passenger? Also, how do I get out?

Tags: sleeping-dogs

I was trying to buy noodles from a vendor, to prepare to beat up a couple of unruly punks. As I was handing over my money (pressed the 'buy' button, which is *right-click* by default in the PC), a 'Select destination' screen (similar to a taxi 'Select destination' screen) appeared. I forgot if I selected a destination or chose 'cancel'. Anyway, I next found myself inside a bus as a passenger.

I was then forced to ride inside the bus against my will (I was unable to exit by pressing right-click) as it went along its route. I'm not sure if the game detected the *right-click* as 'enter the bus' or if this is a bug. I was forced to reload a previous save, as this is no fun at all.

Screenshots (my character is the only passenger in the bus and wears a hat):
(click on an image to view the larger version)
[image]
[image]

My questions: Is this a bug or is there a normal (non-bug) way to ride the bus as a passenger (not as a driver)? Also, if I suddenly found myself inside a bus, how do I exit? (Right-clicking does not work in my case.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug. Per the [game manual](http://cdn.eidosinteractive.com/mtl/marketing/SleepingDogs/SleepingDog_PC_ENG.pdf), Wei can only hire taxis, and as such it shouldn't be possible to become a passenger on a minibus.

While I've never had this happen myself to test, based on multiple accounts<sup>[[1]](http://forums.sleepingdogs.net/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=2686) [[2]](https://web.archive.org/web/20150912083144/http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?p=32413703)</sup> of this happening to other people it seems that there's no way for you to exit a minibus if you're unfortunate enough to get stuck on one, except by causing the game to reload you at a different point.